# How to use ignored words as separator of matches

Tags: regex

I'm analyzing a query string in the following format:

```
Product:123 or Price:>50 or Price:<100
```

The matches I need are: Product:123, Price:>50, Price:<100

It was working fine with the following regex:

```
[\S]+[:][\S]+
```

However now I have some cases where the query string can have words with whitespace in them such as:

```
New Price:456 or Product Type:Video Game
```

The matches I need are: New Price:456, Product Type:Video Game

The separator of the matches will always be the words AND or OR. I looked some other questions with similarities to my problem and they all seem to use negative lookahead however I'm having a hard time making it work for me.

I was trying to use the negative lookahead to match everything except AND or OR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're looking for:

```
(.+?)(?: or | and |$)
```

This will match text with length 1 or more, until it finds the first `or`, `and` or the end of the string.

In a language like Python, you'd grab all the matches like this:

```
re.findall('(.+?)(?: or | and |$)', 'New Price:456 or Product Type:Video Game')
```

Play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/qUips8/1

Since you're suggesting `AND` should be caught (as well as `and`), you may want to make it case-insensitive:

```
(?i)(.+?)(?: or | and |$)
```

If your language supports regexes like that - look up the reference for your language otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this .`\s*((?:(?!and|or).)*)\s`

[This is a demo on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/c1f72K/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could match the words before the colon matching not a whitespace char or a colon. Then repeat that 0+ times prepending a space.

At the end of the pattern, match either  `and`  `or` or assert the end of the string.

The matches will be in the first capturing group.

```
([^:\s]+(?: [^\s:]+)*:[^:\s]+(?: [^\s:]+)*)(?: (?:and|or)|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^:\s]+` Match 1+ times not a whitespace char or `:`
  - `(?: [^\s:]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and again + times not a whitespace char or `:`
  - `:` Match literally
  - `[^:\s]+(?: [^\s:]+)*` Same pattern as before the `:`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?: (?:and|or)|$)` Match either  `and`,  `or` or assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8XEpm5/1)